# Show list of angular components v2 or v4

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, components

I need to **display a list of angular components from a ts file**. How I can doing?

```
  // file ResolventePage.ts

  listFormulas: IFormula[] = [{
     name: "Formula 1",
     description: "a description",
     element: AComponent1
  }, {
     name: "Formula 2",
     description: "a description 2",
     element: AComponent2
  }, ... ]
```

But I do not know how to place it dynamically within the cycle:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of listFormulas">
   <ion-label>{{ item.name }}</ion-label>

   <!-- Here I need to render the component "item.element" -->
 </ion-item>
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly each `element` in your `listFormulas` is and angular Component.

### Option 1

First import all components in your .ts file, for example:

```js
import { AComponent1} from './AComponent1';
import { AComponent2} from './AComponent2';
// ...
```

Then try this quick hack:

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of listFormulas">
  <ion-label>{{ item.name }}</ion-label>

  <{{item.element.name}}></{{item.element.name}}>
</ion-item>
```

### Option 2

If this doesn't work then here's a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview) of the proper but kind of advanced way to do this. This is a demo from the very detailed official documentation for [loading components dynamically](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html).